# Mocha Chai - Test multiple properties of object

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I want to check if my response object contains mentioned properties using chai should assertion.

Below is my code snippet:

```
chai.request(app)
        .post('/api/signup')
        .send(
            data
        )
        .then(function (response) {
            response.should.have.status(200);
            response.body.should.have.property('active', 'mobileNumber', 'countryCode', 'username', 'email', 'id', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'location');
            done();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            done(error);
        })
```

But I am getting below error:
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found how to achieve it using mocha chai-should,

Function name is `.should.have.keys()`
Just pass the properties to this function and it will check they should be present in the object you are testing.

bellow is the code

```
response.body.should.have.keys('active', 'mobileNumber', 'countryCode', 'username', 'email', 'id', 'organisationId', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'location');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're exclusively utilising Chai (in Postman, for example), the following string of functions will successfully aid you:

```
response.body.to.include.all.keys("active", "mobileNumber");
```

[The full list of API's (including an example of the above) can be found here.](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/)